# MyBatis mapper to call a PROC with multiple IN parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, mybatis

I'm trying to design a small CRUD tool, and so far every facet (the Rich Faces UI and Managed Beans,
validation, the mySQL database, etc.) is going fine, but not the myBatis piece.

I'm relatively new to myBatis and am keeping the users guide and API close at hand, but there
are still some things that just won't come together for me, and one is any call to a procedure
involving multiple IN parameters.  Here is an example:

This from the DB set up scripts:

```
create procedure MY_FOO_PROC (IN valA VARCHAR(15), IN valB CHAR(1))
    begin
        select blah from blah where blah = valA and blah = valB etc.;
    end
```

This from MyMapper.java:

```
public interface MyMapper {
List<MyFooClass> getProgress (
        @Param("valA") String valueA, @Param("valB") String valueB);
}
```

This from MyMapper.xml:

```
<select id="getProgress" parameterType="map" 
    resultMap="MyFooMap" statementType="CALLABLE">
    { call MY_FOO_PROC (
        #{valA, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
        #{valB, mode=IN, jdbcType=CHAR}
    )}
</select>
```

And finally this from my DAO class:

```
public static List<MyFooClass>
        doGetProgress (String valueA, String valueB) {
    SqlSession session = MyBatisConnectionFactory.getInstance().getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
    EsparMapper mapper = session.getMapper(MyMapper.class);
    List<MyFooClass> listFoo = mapper.getProgress(valueA, valueB);  // line which originates exception below
    session.close();
    return listFoo;
}
```

The result:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE dbname.MY_FOO_PROC; expected 2, got 1
### The error may involve my.package.names.getProgress-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
```

I will note that I have also tried:

1. creating a POJO with variables valA and valB and getters/setters for
   each,
2. making `parameterType="PojoClass"` in the XML,
3. skipping the `session.getMapper()` and creating an instance of PojoClass,
4. and calling `session.selectList("getProgress", pojoInstance);`

with the nearly identical result (i.e. wrong number of arguments).

Very little help on net search, most telling me to do what I think I have already done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're missing a comma in the procedure call.

```
<select id="getProgress" parameterType="map" 
    resultMap="MyFooMap" statementType="CALLABLE">
    { call MY_FOO_PROC (
        #{valA, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR} , --<--- this
        #{valB, mode=IN, jdbcType=CHAR}
)} 
</select>
```

Comment: Simple mistakes like this are the most frustrating.  Thank you and Merry Christmas!